# iOS handling crash EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV) with source code

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have received the following error from one of our clients with an exact place where the crash happen.
Error report:

```
Symbolize build number: 89778 
2Incident Identifier: 8B5F5ADE-295C-4596-8B34-37280A38511A
3Hardware Model:      iPhone13,2
4Process:             Glip [73149]
5Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/D2CA9563-630A-470F-BC84-A9E6546D5B71/SomeApp.app
6Identifier:          SomeApp
7Version:             89778 (21.2.35)
8AppStoreTools:       12E506
9AppVariant:          1:iPhone13,2:14
10Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
11Role:                unknown
12Parent Process:      launchd [1]
13Coalition:           com.glip.mobile [7033]
14
15
16Date/Time:           2021-07-06 18:29:00.1537 -0700
17Launch Time:         2021-07-06 18:28:56.2301 -0700
18OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.6 (18F72)
19Release Type:        User
20Baseband Version:    1.71.01
21Report Version:      104
22
23Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGSEGV)
24Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
25Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
26Termination Signal: Segmentation fault: 11
27Termination Reason: Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
28Terminating Process: Glip [73149]
29Triggered by Thread:  0
30
31Thread 0 name:
32Thread 0 Crashed:
330   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018ed62ea4 __CFStringChangeSizeMultiple + 148 (CFString.c:1032)
341   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018ed5d874 __CFStringAppendBytes + 708 (CFString.c:1149)
352   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018ed4d800 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 9220 (CFString.c:8375)
363   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018ed619fc _CFStringAppendFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 68 (CFString.c:7556)
374   CoreFoundation                    0x000000018ec8af58 -[__NSCFString appendFormat:] + 120 (CFObject.m:462)
385   Pendo                             0x0000000114173794 -[NSString(IIOStringUtils) pnd_toHexString:length:] + 116
396   Pendo                             0x00000001141733cc -[NSString(IIOStringUtils) pnd_SHA256] + 112
```

The code responsible for the crash is the following:

```
//my stack trace is get called from this method (don't think its matter in that case)
- (nonnull NSString *)pnd_SHA1 {
  unsigned int outputLength = CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH;
  unsigned char output[outputLength];
  CC_SHA1(self.UTF8String, [self pnd_UTF8Length], output);
  return [NSString pnd_toHexString:output length:outputLength];
}
- (NSString *)pnd_SHA256 {
    unsigned int outputLength = CC_SHA256_DIGEST_LENGTH;
    unsigned char output[outputLength];
    
    CC_SHA256(self.UTF8String, [self pnd_UTF8Length], output);
    return [self pnd_toHexString:output length:outputLength];
}

- (NSString*)pnd_toHexString:(unsigned char*) data length:(unsigned int)length {
    NSMutableString* hash = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length * 2];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        [hash appendFormat:@"%02x", data[i]];
        data[i] = 0;
    }
    return [hash copy];
}
```

From quick look I immediately blamed the following line:

```
[hash appendFormat:@"%02x", data[i]];
```

So I reproduced the crash by:`[hash appendFormat:nil];`
And the local report I got: (which is similar BUT not exact)

```
Process:               MyApp [45754]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EAEA42C2-3B8F-48EF-B1D3-BEA68FE046A0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DE83DA67-70A9-4ECF-92B9-526137C6E4B3/MyApp
Identifier:            PendoDevelopmentApp
Version:               1.0 (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd_sim [24742]
Responsible:           SimulatorTrampoline [957]
User ID:               502

Date/Time:             2021-07-21 14:42:56.804 +0300
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.15.7 (19H1217)
Report Version:        12
Bridge OS Version:     5.4 (18P4663)
Anonymous UUID:        74B25560-EFCE-769F-F0B4-E4DD4C6B09A4

Sleep/Wake UUID:       F52FC80E-F86E-4813-B352-D0A7B5FF87B2

Time Awake Since Boot: 120000 seconds
Time Since Wake:       6700 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Segmentation fault: 11
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0xb
Terminating Process:   exc handler [45754]

VM Regions Near 0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 000000010f038000-000000010f0bc000 [  528K] r-x/r-x SM=COW  /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/EAEA42C2-3B8F-48EF-B1D3-BEA68FE046A0/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DE83DA67-70A9-4ECF-92B9-526137C6E4B3/MyApp

Application Specific Information:
CoreSimulator 732.18.6 - Device: iPhone 11 Pro Max (EAEA42C2-3B8F-48EF-B1D3-BEA68FE046A0) - Runtime: iOS 13.0 (17A577) - DeviceType: iPhone 11 Pro Max

Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff23b1df08 __CFStringAppendFormatCore + 536
1   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff23b395cc _CFStringAppendFormatAndArgumentsAux2 + 60
2   com.apple.CoreFoundation        0x00007fff23accba8 -[__NSCFString appendFormat:] + 184
3   io.pendo.PendoSDKFramework      0x000000010f35061d -[NSString(IIOStringUtils) pnd_toHexString:length:] + 109 (NSString+IIOStringUtils.m:111)
4   io.pendo.PendoSDKFramework      0x000000010f35010f -[NSString(IIOStringUtils) pnd_SHA256] + 175 (NSString+IIOStringUtils.m:57)
```

and fixed the code as follows:

```
+ (NSString*)pnd_toHexString:(unsigned char*)data length:(unsigned int)length {
    
    if (data == nil || data == NULL) {
        IIOCriticalLog(@"hash diget is nil");
        return nil;
    }
    NSMutableString* hash = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:length * 2];
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02x",data[i]];
        if (str == nil) {
            IIOCriticalLog(@"hash diget was corrupted");
            return nil;
        }
        [hash appendString:str];
        data[i] = 0;
    }
    return [hash copy];
}
```

The problem that I am still not 100% sure how it could happen for only this specific client as for how the appendString could get a nil.
Maybe somebody had a similar issue.

Comment: @Martin R maybe you can share some insights what can be the issue here

Comment: I have no idea. But what seems strange to  me that the crash report has `pnd_SHA256` in the call stack but you claim that it occurs when called from `pnd_SHA1`. Also the latter method calls `[NSString pnd_toHexString:length]` as a *class method* and not the instance method.

Comment: If `length==0` you are initializing the MutableString with capacity 0. In some cases it is much easier to just do.. `NSMutableString* hash = @"";` Because in a MutableString with capacity 0 @"" does not fit in. which is not nil but an empty string. And change to `if (data == NULL || length==0) { return ...}`. Data is never nil, it is an C pointer so just use NULL.

Comment: @MartinR u right my error log retrieved from a more advanced branch. Edited and added stack trace from exact place. I am jut not sure that [hash appendFormat:nil];
is the correct way to reproduce the issue, maybe something else trigged the error. Client stack trace includes another 2 further calls that my stack trace doesnt has.

Comment: @OlSen totally I agree with all your points its just not so related to the issue I have

Comment: @MartinR maybe u have an idea what I could try in this case?

Comment: from what we can see here i have not much of an extended clue whats wrong.. personally thinking this `CC_SHA256(self.UTF8String, [self pnd_UTF8Length], output);` is suspicious, specially the last Argument. Maybe you can share this functions content and declaration.

Comment: I think there is not enough documentation on it:
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/CC_SHA256.3cc.html
its part of the CommonCrypto/CommonDigest.h